# Is broken tablet screen unsafe to use

Tags: lcd, tablet

I have a tablet with a broken screen apart of this screen became white all the the time while the rest of it is normal ..
[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV2lX.jpg) 
the touch function is normal even in this white area..
there is a screen protector on the screen 
of course the screen must be replaced .. But I want to know:
is there a chance  that a harmful liquid or vapor or harmful gas can leak  from the broken screen....
I'm concerned mainly about  MERCURY leak !
Is it safe to use ..if not why ?

Answer (score 0):

The LCD display of a tablet is not too unsafe to use in case it is broken.

Except, if excessive pressure is applied in the broken area the '[Touch Screen Digitizer](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi3ta-Rk4nOAhUIq48KHaAEBbYQtwIIXDAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DOT97TS_SOI4&usg=AFQjCNHZPGqBT69fecQmdw78elZvPXsmMQ&bvm=bv.127984354,d.c2I)' present immediately behind the display would be damaged rendering the touch screen inoperable.

Anyway it's best to replace the broken display as soon as possible.

Comment: Nah, no need to replace a broken screen at all, if it's still okay for the user.

Answer (score 0):

A modern tablet LCD display is most likely backlit using LEDs, so there is no mercury at all.

> LCD televisions and monitors typically use cold cathode fluorescent lamps (CCFLs) to illuminate the screen. Most CCFLs contain mercury, and therefore questions arise as to the best way to handle LCD equipment at the end of its life.
>
> The latest generation of LCD equipment has seen LCD manufacturers replacing 
>   CCFLs with mercury-free light emitting diode (LED) backlights. The move to 
>   LED backlighting is gathering pace, with companies such as Sharp Electronics of Japan aiming to have all their high definition LCD televisions LED backlit by 2012.
>
> Source: http://www.alr.ie/Download/Mercury_in_waste_LCD_backlights_summary_research_report.63ad9220.11115.pdf

I would be rather concerned about injury from the sharp lines of the broken glass. However, a foil could prevent touching them directly.